# PSR-4 autoloading issue

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

**Problem:**

I have the following file structure

```
-api (contains index.php)
--src
---vendor
----auth (contains auth.php)
----bin
----composer
----nesbot
----rbdwllr
----sympfony
```

here is my composer.json

```
{
        "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AuthSpace\\": "/auth",
            "Tests\\": "/rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt/tests",
            "Symfony\\Polyfill\\Mbstring\\": "/symfony/polyfill-mbstring",
            "Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\": "/symfony/translation",
            "ReallySimpleJWT\\Helper\\": "/rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt/src/Helper",
            "ReallySimpleJWT\\Exception\\": "/rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt/src/Exception",
            "ReallySimpleJWT\\": "/rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt/src",
            "": "/nesbot/carbon/src"
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/src/vendor/autoload.php';

$argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
$tokenCode = $_GET['tokenCode'];

include 'config/database.php';
include 'objects/program1.php';
include 'auth.php';

use ReallySimpleJWT\Token;
use Carbon\Carbon;

$secret = "somesecret";

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "GET") {

    if ($_GET['url'] == "bankquery") {

        if($tokenCode===NULL){
            echo "no correct token provided";
            print($results);
        } else {
        $results = Token::validate($tokenCode, $secret);
        if ($results = 1){

$var = new AuthClass();
$var = AuthClass::checkTime($tokenCode);

} else {
    echo "no correct token provided";
}
    }

} else {
    echo "some GET other query";
}

?>
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php namespace AuthSpace;

use ReallySimpleJWT\Token;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthClass{

public static function checkTime($tokenCode){

// getting payload from token code by accessing the composer dependency method in a class Token
$received = Token::getPayload($tokenCode);

return $received;
}}
?>
```

I've generated the autoload using `composer dump-autoload`, checked the prs4 links - they all seem to show correct directory and namespace linking.

But nontheless, after running index.php file i keep getting the following error, but don't know why.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'AuthSpace\AuthClass' not
>   found

Comment: File with class definition should have the same name as class. So for `AuthClass` you should have `src/auth/AuthClass.php`.

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm!

Comment: Why do you have the autoloading definitions for the vendor packages inside your OWN `composer.json`? They do not belong there. Autoloading other packages is the task of Composer itself: You require a package, and include the `vendor/autoload.php`, and then you can start using classes from that package.